# iOS - UIScrollView content size set to zero

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, size, contentsize

Basically my question would really be, would there be a problem if I set the content size width or height of a scroll view to zero (0).

For example: `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100,0);`

Basically I'm trying to disable the vertical scroll. I tried to set the content size height same as the actual scroll view height. But apparently it's not working. It has this small extra chunk of space thus making vertical scrolling possible. I tried using zero as the content size height and it worked like a charm.

Problem here now is that I'm thinking if there might be consequences in doing this. If there is someone who knows please inform me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `Scrollview.scrollEnabled = NO`?

Comment: @CodaFi: Doing that will make both horizontal and vertical disabled for scrolling. What i need is to have only one of them disabled, specifically the vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you display the `contentSize` of a `UIScrollView` before you change it, you'll find it has been initialised to `0,0`.  So, it's probably safe to return it to that setting.

Comment: Thanks man. Tried it myself after reading your answer. It seems safe. My next question would be is it good practice to do so?